# Non-Conventional MSWord Formatting Using Baselines

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2016, styles

I'd asked this question "yesterday" over on Graphic Design SE, but I was prompted that SuperUser would be more useful in what I'm trying to accomplish. My question is regarding the use of baselines, but keep in mind that I have a copy of MSOffice 2016 Home & Student.

I'm attempting to write VBA to perform individual character adjustment within my entire document:

```
Sub RandomizeBaseline()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim char As Variant
    Dim baseline As Double
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    For Each char In rng.Characters
        baseline = Rnd() * 2 - 1
        char.Font.Position = baseline
    Next char
End Sub
```

The intention of this to begin with is to make a document look as if it was typed on a typewriter. I've already got a monospace font to work with, but with the way that MSWord parses this makes the randomized baseline values either -1, 0, or 1. Setting these to decimal values to make the baseline shift less dramatic apparently truncates to just zero and doesn't shift anything at all. The code does parse through every single character on the document, seen by the editing history when clicking on 'Undo', but there is no visible difference. How should I fix this for my intended ultra specific project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question - imagine that. I didn't account for the fact that I could reasonably "space out" the baselines with a variable randomizer. The code for this is as follows:

```
Sub RandomizeBaseline()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim char As Variant
    Dim baseline As Double
    Dim counter As Integer
    
    ' Set the range to the entire document
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    
    ' Initialize the counter
    counter = 0
    
    ' Loop through each character in the range
    For Each char In rng.Characters
        ' Increment the counter
        counter = counter + 1
        
        ' Check if the counter is a multiple of 10
        If counter Mod 10 = 0 Then
            ' Generate a random baseline value between -1 and 1
            baseline = Rnd() * 2 - 1
            
            ' Apply the baseline position to the character
            char.Font.Position = baseline
        End If
    Next char
End Sub
```